# Problema con stablecoin Blockchain

Tags: code

Buongiorno ho scritto il codice del mio stablecoin ma ho bisogno che sia visionato da un esperto per correggerlo eventualmente e creare le proxy e magari cominciare la programmazione della propria Blockchain

Comment: Please provide the code for your stablecoin along with specific issues or errors you're encountering to receive assistance.